# A little trouble with derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

I have completed calculus 1 but every so often I still get a litte confused on some basic derivatives. I will give an example, I am not sure if my answer is correct but I will show my work.

$ d/dx$  for $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}$

I used the quotient rule, so I got $\frac{\sqrt{x}(1/x)-(\ln x)((1/2)x^{-1/2})}{x}$

I think I am having trouble simplifying. Because I am trying to use this limit so that I can use the alternating series test so I need to show that the function is decreasing.

Here is what I attempted for the simplification

I wrote $f'(x)=((\sqrt x/x)-\ln x)/(2x \sqrt x )=\sqrt x-\ln x/(2x^{5/2})$

But I am not sure if this is correct or if it even allows me to conclude decreasing. Any help suggestions or anything is very appreciated. Thank you all

Comment: You don't have to use \$\$ around every part of an equation. You can just put \$\$ around an entire equation. Functions like $\ln$ have a general command in mathmode by \ln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac1x-(\ln x)\frac12x^{-1/2}}x\;,$$

which is correct. Multiplying numerator and denominator by $x^{1/2}$ will clean up both terms in the numerator quite a bit: it will turn the $\sqrt{x}$ in the first term into $x$, which will cancel with the $\frac1x$, and it will get rid of the $x^{-1/2}$ in the second term. We now have

$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\frac12\ln x}{x^{3/2}}\;.$$

Multiplying top and bottom by $2$ looks like a good idea now:

$$f'(x)=\frac{2-\ln x}{2x^{3/2}}\;.$$

Now it should be much easier to decide where $f'(x)$ is negative.

Comment: Hi Brian, I have a quick notational question if you don't mind: what are your thoughts on using Leibniz's notation to write $\frac{df}{dx}(x)$ for the derivative of a function  $f$ evaluated at a point $x$? To further illustrate my question, here’s an example using this notation: given $f(x)=x^{2}$, then $\frac{df}{dx}(x) = 2x$. I noticed many authors will just write $\frac{df}{dx} = 2x$ instead, but since the derivative of a function is a function shouldn't we be writing $\frac{df}{dx}(x) = 2x$? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @MathDoctor: $\frac{df}{dx}$ is properly thought of as the result of applying the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $y$: $\frac{d}{dx}(y)$. It’s true that this is a function of $x$, so one could write $\left(\frac{d}{dx}(y)\right)(x)$, or $\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$ for short, but I wouldn’t: it’s simpler and more conventional to write $f'(x)$, where $f(x)=y$. Frankly, I prefer to avoid Leibniz’s notation altogether except in the relatively few contexts in which it really does aid the intuition or otherwise make things easier.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, Brian. I only have one follow up question: in the first sentence, did you mean to write "$\frac{df}{dx}$ *is properly thought of as the result of applying the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $\color{red}{y}$*: $\frac{d}{dx}(\color{red}{y})$" or  "$\frac{df}{dx}$ *is properly thought of as the result of applying the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $\color{red}{f}$*: $\frac{d}{dx}(\color{red}{f})$"? That way we could write $\left(\frac{d}{dx}(f)\right)(x)$ or $\frac{df}{dx}(x)$.

Comment: @MathDoctor: I was treating $y$ as essentially synonymous with $f$; if you think of $y$ as a variable rather than as a function of $x$, then replacing my $y$ with $f$ would indeed be preferable.